# Apple Numbers IF rules with checkboxes

Tags: numbers, iwork

I have a column A with checkboxes 
and a column G with Currency

can I do a formula to get the total of G only when the checkbox is not tick?

in the same idea, I have some dates in column B, and I like to get also the total of G (doesn't mater the checkbox this time) when in the current month (or the idea between a 30days period, I suppose something to do with DATEIF) but this I suppose I can do with something like :

`SUMIF(B,MONTH(6),G)` 
however this is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A look at [`SUMIFS`](https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/8.1/#/ffa59150db) and [`SUMIF`](https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/8.1/#/ffa58cd24e) in the help files will point you in the right direction.

#### First case:

Total all currency in column when checkbox is not ticked.  A checkbox not ticked returns `false`, whereas ticked is `true`.  The column headers are named in the example table so the formula in the screenshot reflects those names in the place of the column letter designations.

Formula: `=SUMIF(A, false, G)`

[image: Formula]

#### Second case:

Total by month.  The trick is to get a valid date value.  The formula below is a starting point.
Formula for June in the example below: `=SUMIFS($Currency,$Date,">=2018/"&MONTH(D7)&"/01",$Date,"<=2018/"&MONTH(D7)&"/30")`

For details on the `SUMIFS` function, see the help documents.

[image: SUMIFS formula]

NOTE: the Month 'June' is actually a date 2018/6/1 formatted as month name in this example.  One could substitute the current month this way: `MONTH(NOW)` but note that the formula will change each time the file is opened.  So if opened in July, that will be reflected in the formula. See the `This month total` in the example below.

[image: Formula example]

#### Sample Table

[image: Example Table]

Comment: that's perfect thank you, I didn't think checkbox was actually simple boolean but that actually make sense

Comment: Glad it worked!